# Why isn't `inotifywatch --recursive /proc -v` able to see all created directories in `/proc`?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, filesystems, inotify

In one terminal I run the following command, which generates lots of directories in `/proc` over time:

`$ while true; do /bin/echo helloworld | cat -; echo $$; sleep 3s; done`

Then after several minutes, I inspect the output of `inotifywatch`, which contains only a few directories:

```
$ sudo inotifywatch --recursive /proc -v
Establishing watches...
Setting up watch(es) on /proc
OK, /proc is now being watched.
Total of 5718 watches.
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
^Ctotal  access  close_nowrite  open  filename
1558   540     509            509   /proc/
816    272     272            272   /proc/1529/
168    56      56             56    /proc/437/
105    35      35             35    /proc/3496/
57     19      19             19    /proc/1/
42     14      14             14    /proc/419/
38     22      8              8     /proc/1632/
21     7       7              7     /proc/1120/
12     4       4              4     /proc/sys/kernel/
12     4       4              4     /proc/211/
12     4       4              4     /proc/219/
6      2       2              2     /proc/292/
6      2       2              2     /proc/415/
6      2       2              2     /proc/568/
```

Why isn't `inotifywatch --recursive /proc -v` able to see all created directories in `/proc`?

Is it because that `/proc` is a pseudo-filesystem and that `inotifywatch` only works with real filesystems? If so, why is `inotifywatch` then able to output a few directories (see above)?

I've also tried to execute `inotifywatch` using `sudo`, but the results are the same.

**OS**:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: What is it you expect to see and do not?

Comment: I expect to see the directories `/proc/<pid>` of the many processes spawned by the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot watch `/proc` or any other pseudo-fs with inotify.

From [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html):

> Inotify reports only events that a user-space program triggers
> through the filesystem API.  As a result, it does not catch remote
> events that occur on network filesystems.  (Applications must fall
> back to polling the filesystem to catch such events.)  Furthermore,
> various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts are not
> monitorable with inotify.

Comment: Thank you.
Do you know if's possible to make `inotifywatch` output files created in a specific directory? I can only make it output a list of events that happened for that directory (e.g. `access`, `open`, ...)